# What is the case and data behavior when I deactivate a mobile user in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I see you can delete data and cases if you delete a mobile worker. But if I just deactivate a mobile worker, what happens to the data and cases associated with that mobile worker? If I need cases to be taken over by a new mobile worker, should I reassign before deactivating the old mobile worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deactivate a mobile user all the forms and cases created by that user remain intact and unaffected.

If there are cases owned by the mobile worker being deactivated that require further follow up then yes, you should re-assign them to another user. You can do this at any time (before or after deactivating the user).